# Missing CORS HTTP header in Google Geocoding Web Service

Tags: javascript, jquery, google-geocoding-api

I'm using [Google Geocoding API](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/geocoding/index) (Web Service, not through the geocoder object in Google Maps API) in a Javascript aplication with jQuery so I'm using `$.getJSON` to get the geocoding response.
Until Yesterday, `HTTP` response headers included "Access-Control-Allow-Origin:" header, so I had no problem with browsers supporting CORS.
This morning I realized that this header was removed from the HTTP response so my application cannot access json results anymore.
Could anyone help me find why that header was removed? I think geocoding service is of no use if it is not CORS compatible.

Note: I'm not using geocoder from maps api because google advise to use web service for static kwnon address geocoding and I had less problems with `OVER_QUERY_LIMIT` using web service than geocoder.

Comment: seems to be fixed now.

Comment: Yes it does. Did you have the same problem? Any idea if this was due to service maintenance or something similar? At the beginning I thought I was overcoming some service limit, but then I made some usage estimation and I cannot be even near to the limits. Anyway, thanks for having a look.

Comment: I noticed that it didn't work(there wasn't only the header-issue, the response was empty when requested via ajax when inspecting it via firebug->network, but I was able to get a response when I call the address directly in the browser). A hour later it was working well, so I guess it was a temporarily problem with the service, I can't tell you more.

Comment: you may [report a bug](http://code.google.com/p/gmaps-api-issues/issues/)